# Intellij 2018.3: Import Settings Mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I have exported my settings from one instance of IDEA into a `.jar` via the **File > Export Settings** dialog on my Ubuntu machine.

Now I want to  import these settings on my Mac running IDEA 2018.3.
However I don't see the option to import my `.jar`?
It used to be under **File > Import Settings**, but it is not there anymore.
Searching for *import settings* also yields no results.

Did I miss something?
Is this a regression from Jetbrains part?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had enabled **Sync settings** on my Mac, but not on my Ubuntu machine.
When syncing is enabled the option disappears from the menu.

Found it here: [source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202548#focus=streamItem-27-3167587-0-0).